# How can pipe data in python without cat command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have the following working code in 
**first.py**:

```
import os 
os.system('cat python_better_than_java.wav')
```

which I can execute like this

```
python first.py |  ffmpeg -y -f wav -i pipe:0 -f mp3 - >hi.mp3
```

this works.

I want do this in a pythonic way, so I edited **first.py** to this:

```
import sys
with open('python_better_than_java.wav', 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
sys.stdout.write(content)
```

and executed it using:

```
python first.py | ffmpeg -y -f wav -i pipe:0 -f mp3 - >hi.mp3
```

but then it produces the following error:

```
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

How can I reproduce **cat** in python?

Comment: What happens if you do `python first.py > output` and then `diff output python_better_than_java.wav`?

Comment: @Duncan Binary files t.py.wav and u.py.wav differ

Comment: It should work.  Is the size of `output` equal to `python_better_than_java.wav`? What operating system / python version are you using?

Comment: 4kb size difference in file. but possible to play both file.i am using  window 7 32 bit and python 2.7

Comment: It's a shame this is a duplicate, 'cause there's was lot of rep to be had...